# in php is there a way to dump "all" variable names with their corresponding value?

Tags: php, debugging

if the title seems too vague..
uhm i wanted to display every variable that i used to generate a page along with their variable names and values, is it possible and how?

```
    foreach($_SESSION as $varname => $value) {
        print "<b>".$varname."</b> = $value <br/>";
    }
```

^the above sample is what i use to display all session variables, what if i need to display the variables i set to display the page? are they registered also in some form of an array or should i also echo them individually?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) which will give you an array of all variables declared in the scope that the function is called including globals like `$_SESSION` and `$_GET`. I would suggest printing it like so:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r(get_defined_vars(), true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: had problems with formatting the results on how they get printed out but it seems i found a better solution from Josiah's answer below http://au.php.net/get_defined_vars#73608

Comment: Good answer :) It helped to me.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to do this is with [get_defined_vars()](http://au.php.net/get_defined_vars).

**From the Documentation**

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables, within the scope that get_defined_vars() is called.

Producing a var_dump of this array will provide you with an extensive list.

```
var_dump( get_defined_vars() );
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple other interesting functions in the same area are get_defined_constants() and get_included_files()...